# Negative Binomial Vs Geometric

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I am trying to get the difference between these two distributions. I think I understand them but the negative binomial has me a bit confused.

The Geometric is the probability of some amount of successes before the first failure.

The Negative binomial is the portability of some amount of successes before a specified number of failures? for example the number of successes before the 8th failure?

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but I think most people think of it the other way around, reversing "success" and "failure." Of course that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A geometric distribution (on $\{0,1,2,...\}$) is usually presented as the count of *failures* before the first *success*, in an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with success rate $p$. $$X\sim\mathcal{Geo}_0(p) \iff \Bbb P(X=x) ~=~ (1-p)^xp\; \mathbf 1_{x\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}}$$

A negative binomial distribution is usually presented as the count of *successes* before specified amount of *failures*, $r$, in an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate, $p$.

$$X\sim\mathcal{N\!B}(r, p) \iff \Bbb P(Y=y) ~=~ \binom{y+r-1}{x}p^y(1-p)^r\; \mathbf 1_{y\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}}$$

So the Geometric Distribution is a member of the family of Negative Binomial Distributions, with the identification of failure and success inverted. $$\mathcal {Geo}_0(p)=\mathcal{N\!B}(1,1-p)$$